# how to return a value of promise in Protractor

Tags: protractor

```
Panel Property Object:
this.IncSummary = element.all(by.css('#incidentList h5'));

Common function:
//Get the Text of Summary
exports.getIncSummary = function (IncId) {  
console.log("executing getIncSummary function");
Panel.IncSummary.then(function(items){
    console.log("Summary items = " +items);
    (items[IncId].getText()).then(function(txt){
            console.log("summary text = "+ txt);                                
        }); 
    return items[IncId].getText();          
  });
 };


 Using this function in my test:

 it('compare the summary text ', function() {   
  CommonFun.getIncSummary(0).then(function(promis){
                    console.log("promis= "+promis);
                });             
  });
```

I am getting following error:

Failed: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Not sure what I am doing wrong, would appreciate any help on this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is just the basic in the js script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `getIncSummary` doesn't return anything. If you wish to get the text for a given locator/index then use `.get()`:

```js
// Panel Property Object:

this.IncSummary = element.all(by.css('#incidentList h5'));


// Common function:

exports.getIncSummary = function (index) {
  return Panel.IncSummary.get(index).getText();
};


// Using this function in my test:

it('compare the summary text ', function() {
  CommonFun.getIncSummary(0).then(function(text){
      console.log(text);
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried returning Panel.IncSummary.get(index).getText(); but it still shows Failed: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined for  CommonFun.getIncSummary(0).then(function(text) line No.

Comment: I get the expected result with this example. Your issue is probably somewhere else in you code.

Comment: Thanks, @Florent it worked, was previously returning from  hence it was returning undefined    `exports.getIncSummary = function (IncId) {  
Panel.IncSummary.then(function(items){                                    
        }); 
   return Panel.IncSummary.get(index).getText();         
  });
 };` changed this to `exports.getIncSummary = function (IncId) {  
Panel.IncSummary.then(function(items){           
  }); return Panel.IncSummary.get(index).getText();  
 };` and it worked :)